# How can I Execute a SQL statement with one of the paramaters to a variable date?

Tags: sql-scripts

What I want to do is to let the system date dictate what my reporting year should be in this query:

```
EXEC [reporting].[Testing]
        @CompanyNames = NULL,
        @ReportYear = 2020
```

to something like this:

```
EXEC [reporting].[Testing]
        @CompanyNames = NULL,
        @ReportYear = YEAR(SYSDATE())
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  You define variables but never use them.

Comment: Can you use `YEAR(CURDATE())`?

Comment: Do you want year or date

Answer (score 0):

you can try this . I hope your reporting is database

```
EXEC [reporting].[Testing]
@CompanyNames = NULL,
@ReportYear = cast(getdate() as date(30))
```